# How to Map kivy buttons to python script file?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a python script `imaging.py` that uses Pillow and and Pandas. The script works perfectly when run.
I am building a UI using Kivy.
I have two buttons `start` and `exit`
How do I map the start button to run `imaging.py`?
In addition, Is it possible to use functions from `imaging.py` inside
`main.py`(runs kivy app) and create separate buttons for each function?
I have my three files : `imaging.py` `main.py` and `my.kv` all in same directory

Comment: in python you should use `import` to load function from other files - and then you can use them in main file. But it needs to put code in functions because if you have all code directly in file then it will run it when you import file - and you can't decide to run it only when you press button. And using `import` many times to run it again it will also not work because `python` remember improted files and it doesn't import them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several things going on here.

First. You should learn how to create a [kivy App](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html).

Second. Any piece of code to be run should have a function that you could call. Ensure that you have a callable function within `imaging.py`. An idea is to put all your `if __name__ == "__main__":` code into a single function `main():` that could then be called in your application.

Third. You should learn how to create a [callback](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html) either in [python](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) or in [kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#binding-to-properties-of-properties) script. These allow for you to call a function when a button is pressed, released, state changed.

You need to learn the [basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/) of kivy in order to implement your backend code into kivy.

Comment: Yes and I just did that. Thanks for the links :)